# Find and extract two substrings from string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some strings (in fact they are lines read from a file). The lines are just copied to some other file, but some of them are "special" and need a different treatment.

These lines have the following syntax:

```
someText[SUBSTRING1=SUBSTRING2]someMoreText
```

So, what I want is: When I have a line on which this "mask" can be applied, I want to store `SUBSTRING1` and `SUBSTRING2` into variables. The braces and the `=` shall be stripped.

I guess this consists of several tasks:

1. Decide if a line contains this mask
2. If yes, get the positions of the substrings
3. Extract the substrings

I'm sure this is a easy task with regex, however, I'm not used to it. I can write a huge monster function using string manipulation, but I guess this is not the "Python Way" to do this.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: I suggest you learn about regex.

Comment: @lugge86 how the sometext and somemoretext looks like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
^[^\[\]]*\[([^\]\[=]*)=([^\]\[=]*)\][^\]\[]*$
```

You can try this.`Group 1`and `Group 2` has the two string you want.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/26

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^[^\[\]]*\[([^\]\[=]*)=([^\]\[=]*)\][^\]\[]*$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "someText[SUBSTRING1=SUBSTRING2]someMoreText\nsomeText[SUBSTRING1=SUBSTRING2someMoreText\nsomeText[SUBSTRING1=SUBSTRING2]someMoreText"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but why such a huge and complicated regex pattern for such a simple problem?

Comment: It's still very complicated. I don't see why you'd need more than `\[(.*?)=(.*?)\]`.

Comment: As far as i can say, this works like a charm! Thank you. The downvote is not justified. However, I have no idea what this expression is doing, guess I have to read some regex stuff...

Comment: @interjay OP says there can be other lines as well.He wants data from lines matching the format OP mentions.Only those lines

Comment: @lugge86 see d demo .On the right side you can see explantion.Do accept as well if it worked for you

Comment: @vks Why is that a problem? The other lines won't match the pattern.

Comment: @interjay your pattern will match a lines like `[zxczx=zxczx=xzcxzc=]` which is not what OP wants :)

Comment: @ vks: your first solution (before the edit) did well, but now, using the shorter expression, I get syntax error: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

`re.search()` returns `None` if it doesn't find a match. `\w` matches an alphanumeric, `+` means 1 or more. Parenthesis indicate the capturing groups.

```
s = """
bla bla
someText[SUBSTRING1=SUBSTRING2]someMoreText"""

results = {}
for line_num, line in enumerate(s.split('\n')):

    m = re.search(r'\[(\w+)=(\w+)\]', line)
    if m:
        results.update({line_num: {'first': m.group(0), 'second': m.group(1)}})

print(results)
```